# Getting issue when passing too large base64 url in ajax call using asp.net core

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, base64

Here is my code,

```
var uploadparameter = {
    base64url: imageData,        
};

$.ajax({
   url: '@(Url.Action("CustomAsyncUpload", "ProductCreation"))',
   type: 'POST',
   data: JSON.stringify(uploadparameter),
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   success: function (data) 
   {

   }
});
```

When I'm passing too large base64 url in ajax call using asp.net core that time i'm facing issue.

So,How to pass too large base64 url in ajax call using asp.net core..?

Thanks, Kaushik.

Comment: Can you provide more info about the issue? Is there an error message? or some sort

Comment: @PetIbaño error message is - requested header is too large.

Comment: Is base64 required when uploading a file? If not, I would suggest using `FormData` for large files.

Comment: Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24939229/7265539)

Comment: @PetIbaño yes bas64 is required, because im implementing crop image functionality so i required.

Comment: Have you tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41169424/2309376) ?

Comment: @SimplyGed Yes.

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing base64 so it has huge amount of string, so until it get upload you will get request timeout error, so Don't pass in base64, send image with **form-data** while uploading.

Comment: anyhow i want to pass base64 url in ajax call because my client requirement is that type.